Will these group sizes improve data coalescing?
I upload a buffer to the GPU that contains a series of "records". The number of records can vary between 50 and 10,000, and all records are the same length (typically ~40,000 float values). I then run a kernel to process the values in the buffer, but only those values that fall within designated "regions" defined across each record. There are approx 200 regions defined, and are of varying sizes between 10 and 100 values in width. The same list of 200 regions applies to every record in the buffer.
The first attempt at the kernel used a global work size of [num records, num regions] and NULL local work size. Each kernel thread processes all values within a region, something like this:
for (int i = regionStart; i <= regionEnd; i++)
{
    buff[i] = do_something(buffer[i]);
}

(While not important to my question, the kernel is also passed a lookup table containing a list of the regions' start and end positions. The kernel looks up get_global_id(0) and get_global_id(1) to calculate regionStart & regionEnd).
I wanted to try and improve performance by making the kernel "more parallel" and hopefully in the process improve memory coalescing, so I changed the global work size to [num records, num regions, 64], and the local work size to [1, 1, 64]. My understanding is that this should now result in 64 kernel threads acting on each region. The kernel code was  updated to this:
int i = get_local_id(2); // 0-64
while (i + regionStart <= regionEnd)
{
    buff[i] = do_something(buffer[i]);
    i += get_local_size(2);
}

Unfortunately the kernel execution time is several times slower than the original.
What am I missing (or not understanding)?
This is running under Windows, on a Radeon Pro WX7100 if that matters.

Assuming that regionStart and regionEnd values are different per group:
Probably drivers of the GPU is vectorizing on local-id values on X dimension, not Z.
Your loop looks like a strided grid pattern and should be parallelized but I guess the global and local id mapping is not fitting well to driver's approach.
Try X-major indexing [64,1,1] and get_local_id(0) for local id values and similar for global-index too.
If there are 64 pipelines per compute unit, then 64 threads should use the GPU well with the strided-grid pattern.
NULL work size was better because driver was choosing a better id-mapping like [64,1].
From Khronos OpenCL Spec:

size_t get_global_linear_id():
For 3D work-groups, it is computed as ((get_global_id(2) -
get_global_offset(2)) * get_global_size(1) * get_global_size(0)) +
((get_global_id(1) - get_global_offset(1)) * get_global_size(0)) +
(get_global_id(0) - get_global_offset(0)).

Linear coalesced id values are get_global_id(0)-major. Simply shuffling the dimension values should give 64x potential compute performance.

The GPU kernel should only compute one single iteration/element of the loop, and all iterations must be independent of each other.
Don't put a loop in the kernel, to make one GPU thread process several elements. This would mean that you are not parallelizing and it will be very slow.
On the host side, run the kernel with the global size as large as there are elements (can be in the billions, the GPU can handle that). Each kernel/thread computes only a single element.
What you are doing with splitting up into region is domain decomposition - you would use that for CPU multithreading - each CPU core/thread gets a region to compute. But GPUs are different, they want vectorization, where each GPU thread gets only one single loop element to compute.
Note: Vectorization is the superior way of parallelization, and is actually backward-compatible with domain decomposition (where each CPU core gets assigned a region of threads/loop elements). OpenCL running in the CPU will do exactly that; plus, it will vectorize on AVX2/AVX-512 SIMD units to make it even faster).
